# LDAP Token Timeout setting

Tags: ldap, jboss6.x

I am very new to LDAP,I have configured LDAP in jboss-6.0.0.Final using following setting in login-config.xml.

```
<application-policy name = "XXXXXX">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag ="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">XXXXXXXXXXX/module-option>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">anonymous</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</module-option>
            <module-option name="baseFilter">(sAMAccountName={0})</module-option> 
            <module-option name="bindDN">XXXXXXXXXXXX</module-option> 
            <module-option name="baseCtxDN">XXXXXXX</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.principal">XXXXXXXX</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.credentials">XXXXXXX</module-option> 
            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">XXXXXXXXXX/module-option>
            <module-option name="roleFilter">(member={1})</module-option>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeID">memberOf</module-option>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN">true</module-option>
            <module-option name="roleRecursion">1</module-option>  
            <module-option name="defaultRole">XXXXXXXX</module-option> 
            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">true</module-option>    
            <module-option name="searchScope">SUBTREE_SCOPE</module-option>
            <module-option name="throwValidateError">true</module-option>   
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

It is working fine and now my lead is asking what have you set for "LDAP Token timeout setting".So i googled it out and found that it some thing for how often server checks for authentication.for e.g if a user already logged in to application and in between password changed how much time will it take to check the password..could you please help me to set this timeout setting ???

Answer (score 0):

LDAP doesn't give you tokens. It either authenticates you or it doesn't. The timeout in servlet-container-based Web systems is the HTTP session timeout, which is configured in `web.xml`. Nothing to do with LDAP whatsoever.

Comment: "user already logged in to application and in between password changed in lDAP how much time will it take to check the new password"... how will this scenario handled in LDAP ??

Comment: I can't make head or tail of that. If the user changes his password why does anybody need to check it? Why is a timeout required on that? In any case LDAP certainly doesn't provide one.